# Avoid copy method in Python

Tags: python

I wrote a function in python implementing the de Casteljau algorithm

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import copy

def decasteljau(P, t):
    N = len(P)
    for k in range(N-1):
        for r in range(N-1-k):
            P[r] = (1-t)*P[r] + t*P[r+1]
    return P[0]
```

And called the function with the following data

```
P = np.array([[1.,1.],[2.,3.],[3.,2.]], dtype=float)
M = 1000
for j in range(M):
    t = decasteljau(P, j/(M-1))
```

which lead to thousands of (wrong) results `[3,2]` for almost all values of `t = j/(M-1)`. I changed the code to

```
def decasteljau(P, t):
    N = len(P)
    Q = copy.copy(P)
    for k in range(N-1):
        for r in range(N-1-k):
            Q[r] = (1-t)*Q[r] + t*Q[r+1]
    return Q[0]
```

so I copied the array `P` before changing it, and now the data is correct. I don't really understand why it works now and I was wondering if there is a solution without the copy method? Thank you!

Here is a data plot without copy method and a data plot with the copy method:

[image: without copy method]
[image]

Obviously, the first plot isn't correct. The first plot has most of it's point in `3,2`, which is not what I want.

Comment: No; if you don't create a copy (there are several ways of creating a copy) you end up modifying the original object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in python you pass link to a variable, not just value, so you modify base list.
All mutable types transmitted as link. You can read more about it in [data types](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html) section of python documentation.

If you want avoid copy function you can just write

```
Q = P[:]
```

And that is all you need :-)

Also there is good answer [how to do right copy of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python)